# Spree - Create users with other role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, cancan, role

I'm trying to create users with different role than user. How can I do it? I didn't see anything about role in the new user function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do following:

```
role =  Spree::Roles.create( name: "something" )
your_user.spree_roles = role
```

Comment: your_user.spree_roles << role